# What does ずっとああ mean?

Tags: meaning

まだ慣れなくってずっとああさ。

Is it roughly "all the way like that"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> まだ慣れなくってずっとああさ。

＝まだ慣れなくて、ずっと、ああ　さ。＝まだ慣れなくて、ずっと、あの様さ。＝まだ慣れなくて、ずっと、あの様子なのです。

***"I'm not accustomed to it yet. So my behavior is always (awkward) as such."***

Comment: I wish someone would explain that down vote, it seems to answer the question well enough--even parsing how to interpret the sentence.